# How can Hitoe touch Ruuko?

Tags: wixoss

During the events of *Selector Infected Wixoss*, it is revealed that when a Selector loses 3 battles...

> her wish is reversed. Hitoe, who wished to make friends, would therefore be unable to touch any potential or current friend without suffering from intense pain. She would also be unable to remember her friends or read any diary entry about them.

Interestingly, the very first episode of *Selector Spread Wixoss* shows Hitoe touching Ruuko without showing any signs of pain.

How is that possible?

Comment: FTR Hitoe also touches Ruko in the last episode of _Selector Infected Wixoss_ without any obvious signs of pain, after she reveals to Ruko and Yuzuki that she regained her memories and appreciated their friendship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that by obtaining a new deck containing an LRIG, the mental effects of losing three battles are not an issue anymore.

This is based on the reasoning that Akira was physically scarred, with her mental scarring coming from the physical and Ulith, whereas Hitoe was mentally scarred - it is also possible (this, by the way, is just an assumption) that her pain was not actually real, and only something her mind created. Knowing Mari Okada's work, this could be quite possible.

Assuming it is a physical issue, she did recognise that she had friends before, as well, and remembering that Yuzuki and Ruko were her friends may have broken the barrier that stopped them from becoming so when Akira beat her in the first season.